# java is not recognized as an internal or external command, variables are set already

Tags: java, solr, java-8

After setting JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171 and adding %JAVA_HOME%\bin to my path, I am still getting this error.  I have checked that the path is correct multiple times and every solution online just says to add these two variables.  Is there any other step to fix this?

I'm getting this error when trying to run "java -jar start.jar" for solr.

Comment: Is this from `cmd.exe`? What is the complete and unabbreviated output of `echo %PATH%`? How about `echo %JAVA_HOME%`? Make sure to do it in the same shell instance where you run `java -jar start.jar`

Comment: JAVA_HOME echos the right value, but it does not show up when I echo PATH,  now after hard coding the value in to path it is working though.  Not sure why this was happening but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added Java Location as the Path variable in your system. The Command Prompt or Powershell can only take you to the path/paths you have already specified.

Add "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\" to the Path variable in your Advanced System Settings->Enviroment Variables->Path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the command in a new DOS shell. If you are using the same one you ran the java command in before setting the path, it won't have the path update.

Answer (score 0):

Don't type path manualy - choose path by [Browse directory] button.
Path looks the same but can be different (maybe encoding of signs)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).